# php mysql update date type from YYYY-mm-dd to mm-dd-YYYY

Tags: php

I have a mysql DATE Field named dDate that is formatted like this: YYY-MM-DD I would like to update all of the records in this field to a different DATE format of MM-DD-YYYY can someone show me how to to this via mySQL query ?

I tried this example but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE address_email SET dDate = DATE_FORMAT(dDate, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

and this:

```
 UPDATE address_email SET dDate = DATE(dDate, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

THANKS SO MUCH FOR THE HELP.

Comment: @Lior Sorry that is what I wanted to write still the same it keeps the YYYY-mm-dd format

Comment: @Lior wait is the format YYYY-MM-DD the default/native format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), it looks like MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format only, and I don't think you can change it.

What you really want to do is format the date when you pull it out of the database, not change the default formatting of the DATE field for your table. When you SELECT, do something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dDate, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM address_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the mysql documentation regarding date_format : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE vechical
SET PDate = DATE_FORMAT('12-08-2012','%d-%m-%y')
WHERE Cust_ID='21';
```

Please correct query for this

Comment: it is better to formate in a select query as MySql will not allow changing the date format.